# How can I create a new Android Studio Project in an Existing GitHub repo?

Tags: android, github

I am new to Android development. I have created a GitHub repo with some files in it. How can I create a new Android Studios Project within this repo?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your new project in File->New->New Project...
Then go to VCS->Enable Version Control, then a new window pops-up and choose Git.
Then you go to your app folder in Android View (left panel) and right click your app folder, menu Git->pull and it will ask you to define a remote origin. There you paste the URL of your project on github.
Then you can do a commit first, (same right click, git, add) then do a pull (because if you don't, you wouldn't be able to push later unless you do a rebase later).
And now your project is synced with Github.
Any problem don't hesitate to send me a private message.
Kind regards!

Comment: A window "Pull Changes" pops up with "None" selected in the "Remote" drop-down and I can't change it.

Comment: Click in remote (it should be blue and underlined) and set up your url pointing to the project in github.